# updating rails to 2.3.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

can you update your 2.3.5 app with just "gem update rails" and change the version # in environment.rb? I did that and lots of errors came out like in console just typing Post.all would show "undefined method `retrieve_connection' for nil:NilClass". Any ideas?

By the way, I have these gems in my environment.rb

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"
config.gem "less"
config.gem "authlogic"
config.gem "be9-acl9", :source => "http://gems.github.com", :lib => "acl9"  
config.gem "hash_extension"
config.gem "prawn"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Ryan and Tomas.

Okay, I took out the gems one by one and whatever code that each required to add to the app one by one, that took awhile but I am satisfied to tell you that it's the acl9 gem.

So what I've done to resolve this.

gem uninstall be9-acl9 (it was an older version anyway)

gem install acl9

NO kidding, that's it.

And it seems that be9-acl9 has changed its name to just acl9. great gem though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to. Show us the errors and stacktrace if you're getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with updating to 2.3.8, but I had

```
config.gem "acl9", :version => "0.11.0"
```

Changing to `"0.12.0"` solves the problem