# Rails upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.3.8 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to upgrade my app from Rails 2.3.4 to 2.3.8..

I went into the environment.rb file, and changed

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

to

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

(**do i need to do something else?**)

I am using **MySQL Server version: 5.1.47**

I am not using bundler

I am running on OS X 10.6.6

Here is my database.yml, which matches my WORKING applications that I created in 2.3.8 (rather than upgrading)

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: _development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

When I do this, any page I load gives the same error.. this same error can be achieved by attempting to build/retrieve a model from the database, the error is this:

```
>> Company.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `retrieve_connection' for nil:NilClass
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1301:in `columns'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:3055:in `attributes_from_column_definition_without_lock'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:66:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2469:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `new'
    from (irb):1
```

**EDIT: Gem List from environment.rb**

```
  config.gem "authlogic"
  config.gem "hpricot"
  config.gem "BlueCloth", :lib => 'bluecloth'
  config.gem "daemons"
  config.gem "gravtastic", :version => '2.2.0'
  config.gem "json"
  config.gem "ruby-rapleaf"
  config.gem "ar-extensions"
  config.gem "url_shortener"
  config.gem 'aws-s3', :version => '>= 0.6.2', :lib => 'aws/s3'
  config.gem 'paperclip', :version => '>= 2.3.1.1'
  config.gem 'omniauth'
```

Comment: This is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892977/updating-rails-to-2-3-6 -- can you post your gems in your application.rb?

Comment: This is most likely the issue. Gems are usually specified in environment.rb, post the contents of that.

Comment: I just commented out ALL the gems, and I'm getting the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasnt a GEM, it was actually a plugin. ACL9 now has a GEM and when I initially started using it, I could only find it in plugin form. SO, for anyone coming through..

I had ACL9 plugin v .11, Rails 2.3.4

Upgraded to Rails 2.3.8 and had to install the ACL9 gem, which is currently at v .12